# Read Excel Text Header Using Python

Tags: python, excel

I am working with a system that generates randomly labeled excel files for requests and I need to parse information out of the Excel Report header. To be clear, I'm not trying to get Rank, ID, Name, From, or Through, I'm trying to extract the date from this example. [Output file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqJc2.png)

You'll notice that the information I want is not contained in any cell, but rather the Excel report formatting. When I import the entire file as a pandas dataframe, the date is not there because the data is not stored in any cell.

This is the only field formatted like that in the file, so I attempted to read the whole file and extract it with a regular expression like this:

```
import re

matches = []
with open('Roster Report.xlsx') as f:
    for line in f:
        matches += re.findall('\[[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/20[0-9]{2}\]',line)
matches
```

But I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 56: character maps to <undefined>`

I've also seen in the package `xlrd` the ability to write to the Excel header using `dump(header="[10/24/2018]"`, but I don't see in the docs how to read data form the header.

Comment: Excel files are not simple text files. You need to use a module which can interact with Excel.

Comment: An xlsx file is an archive file. You can't open it directly with `open`. You'll need to use a proper library, such as `openpyxl` or `xlrd`

Comment: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_headers_footers.html

Comment: @JohnColeman and @DeepSpace, I understand how Excel is not a simple file, but I haven't found a package to parse the metadata in the document header. As mentioned in the question, I've tried `xlrd` but I don't see what in `xlrd` can read the header. @bilbo_strikes_back, I saw something similar using `xlrd` but in both examples, I don't see how to **read** the header, only how to **write** the header.

Comment: xlrd does not write *anything*. It's purely a reader. It doesn't read *all* parts of an Excel file, but it writes no part of an Excel file.

Comment: You are correct, I was confusing `xlrd` with `XlsxWriter` which is a different package. Regardless, `xlrd` does not have a method for reading the file header which is why it was not able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments actually helped me get the answer by pointing me to `openpyxl`. I'm posting it here if anyone else had it.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Roster Report.xlsx')
header_text = str(wb.active.HeaderFooter)
wb.close()
```

I didn't see a way in `xlrd` to read the header<s>, only to write it</s>.

Comment: xlrd does not write anything.

Comment: You are correct that `xlrd` doesn't write. (See more detailed comment above.) I edited the answer to reflect this. The solution is still the same.